# ManyToOne owning side issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Hello everyone.

I have a question because of which I cannot sleep) 
If I have an entity(class) called Product, for instance. And I should link with this product a bunch of images. In a database(MySQL in my case) in would be looking like this - I'd create a table to products and a table for images. And image table would have a field that stores product id.

I understand it at this point. What I don't understand is - when I work with my products and images in ORM(Doctrine2) I should create inversedBy="images"annotation for the Image class, and mappedBy="products" for the Product class. By in my application a Product object is in the owning side of this connection.

What should I do? Should I create ManyToMany relationship, or there is another way?

Thank you.

P.S. the images is an ArrayCollection instance in the Product entity

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question beyond what is described in the documentation for setting up a

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Heck, it even uses "Product" as the entity in the example - just replace "Feature" "Image" and you're set.

Are you saying that you *don't* want a bidirectional relationship?

Comment: When I use that approach - when I create a new Product and add new Images to that Product I should watch it out in a create method of a ProductController but I want to know is there some other way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can one image be used in more than one products? If I assume correct, it cannot. Therefor I would go for `OneToMany` relationship.

Comment: No - this is the case. If it was like that - I would choose the Product entity as the owning side of that relation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've dealt with this. What I did is added cascade={"persist"} to the inverse side of the relation and in the addImage method of the Product class I've added:
public function addImage($image)
{
    $this->images->add($image);
    $image->setProduct($this);
    return $this;
}